# How to Integrate ( Recurring+chainpayment ) OR ( Recurring+parallel ) payment using paypal?

Tags: php, recursion, paypal

I Have implemented individual delayed chained payment and recurring payment using pay-pal individual. But my requirement is that i want to integrate both in one.

Let me explain with Example:

I have site in that i want to implement chain payment b/w

```
Merchant->Admin->Dealer
```

In that Merchant have dealer and merchant pay to admin recursively and admin want to pay after one month to dealer recursively but i want to make it recursively every month that amount deduct from merchant account and add to admin and after one month it recursively add to dealer.

So i have tried but i could not succeeded. is it possible with paypal i can add another payment gateway through which i can do this but preference is paypal.